# performance issue due to huge number of dom elemets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage where I repeats div with same class thousand times in a loop due to which  browser engine just seemed to choke.

Is there any way of improving a page with a lot of dom elements? or infinite scroll on dom elemnts?

```
<div class="test"> content 1</div>
<div class="test"> content 2</div>
<div class="test"> content 3</div>
<div class="test"> content 4</div> //so on like 10000 same divs in loop
```

Comment: If you are infinite scrolling, you can remove dom elements as they leave the page and re-add them when they enter the page again.

Comment: Search for "virtual scrolling" you might find something helpful. http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2012/06/23/virtual-rendering-1000000-items-efficiently/

Comment: Also, if you are adding the divs in a loop, do you mean each iteration adds a div to the DOM? If so a first quick win would be to add multiple/all divs in one go to prevent reflow. e.g. with `document.createDocumentFragment()` Of course the mentioned virtual scrolling solution would be most elegant, but adding on each iteration is a first bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

if I were you I would first place a set of divs that fills the screen. When you scroll to the bottom of the page you could get another couple of elements. then repeat the process. If you reach the amount of divs you want you could start append elements from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can load first 20 or so, and others can be loaded asynchronously with AJAX methods, triggered by scroll or visibility of one of the bottom. Unloading top DOMs is not recommended anyway. General suggestion for best performance practice is to avoid using large numbers of DOM elements with ID tags.

See more about that [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)